# Sony qx1 live view refresh rate

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

What is the maximum refresh rate in live view mode from qx1 to a PC? I.e. can I call the http API at 20-30 HZ?
Also, when camera is in live view mode, will triggering a shot result in focus 'hunting', so is it necessary to exit the live view mode before triggering a shot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about camera hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum frame rate of live view depends on the implementation of client application and Wi-Fi connectivity. The camera will return the live view up to 30fps. And the client doesn’t need to stop getting live view data before taking picture.